# Render New Views Within a Div Based on Click of Button | AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, single-page-application

Hi I am trying to render a new view based on clicks of a button in a navbar. However, it is not working.

Here is my HTML Code:

```
            <!-- Links to all the pages with data entry forms -->
            <div id="data_links" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" title="Home Page" ng-click = "ChangeView('instructions')"> Home </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Modify views here -->
        <div class="main" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
            <main role="main">
                <div ng-view> <!-- Where we will inject html --> </div>
            </main>
        </div>

<!-- Application Files -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/main.js"></script>
```

Here is my app.js:

```
angular.module('DataEntry', [
  'ngRoute'
]).config(function ( $routeProvider ) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('instructions', {
      templateUrl: 'views/instructions.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    });
});
```

Here is my controller main.js:

```
angular.module('DataEntry')
  .controller('MainCtrl',
    function MainCtrl ( $scope, $location ) {
      'use strict';
      $scope.ChangeView = function(view) {
        alert(view);
        $location.url(view);
      }
    });
```

This is my instructions.html page for testing to see if it loads:

```
<div class="module instructions">
    <div class="module_instructions">
        <h1> Testing Loaded! </h1>
        <p> Test <br> 
            Test <br> Test <br> Test 
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to eventually be able to click on multiple links within a navbar, such as home, instructions, etc. and render different views within the ng-view section. However, it is not working right now and I am not sure how to scale it so I can add more .html pages for the different views I want to render. Can someone help me move forward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line
    `<a href="#" title="Home Page" ng-click = "ChangeView('instructions')"> Home`

Can be changed to this:

`<a href="/instructions" title="Home Page"> Home </a>`

You don't need to use a function on your controller to set the url, although you can navigate this way - sometimes you want to redirect the user programatically and this works for those cases.

Also, leaving `href="#"` in that line is causing you a problem. In a non-angular page # is used as  a href placeholder but on an Angular `href="#"` is actually going to be picked up by `$routeProvider` which will try to change the contents of the `ng-view` container. What loads will depend upon how you set up your `.config` section, but is generally not desirable behavior.

As you create more pages, add paths to your `.config` section and you can link to them from your html the same way as I did above with the `/instructions` path.

Here's an example:

```
angular.module('DataEntry', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function ( $routeProvider ) {
  $routeProvider
   .when('instructions', {
      templateUrl: 'views/instructions.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
   })
   .when('faq', {
      templateUrl: 'views/faq.html',
      controller: 'FaqCtrl'
   })
   .when('example', {
      templateUrl: 'views/example.html',
      controller: 'ExampleCtrl'
   })
});
```

and in your markup:

`<a href="/instructions" title="Home Page"> Home </a>`

`<a href="/faq" title="FAQ"> FAQ</a>`

`<a href="/example" title="Example Page"> Example</a>`

Comment: I don't want to reload a page, but I simply want to render different html views within the ng-view section everytime I click on a new button/link. 

Should I just use <button> instead so I don't run into the reload page problem?

Comment: My wording was not correct - this won't actually cause a full page refresh but `href="#"` will reload the content of the `ng-view` container. The example in my answer will render html views in the `ng-view` container.

Comment: Oh thanks it works. I just don't need to add the href="/" actually because my controller will set the $location.path(view); based on my ng-click=ChangeView(view)